# WCF - How do I return a success or failure message using Message Contracts

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, messagecontract

Im using SOAP/XML with MessageContracts and **have to return a specified format** similar to the following:

If validation is successful:

```
<env:Envelope>
    <env:Body>
        <Success xmlns="http://tempuri.org"></Success>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

If it is unsuccessful:

```
<env:Envelope>
    <env:Body>
        <Failure xmlns="http://tempuri.org"></Failure>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Take for instance, the following method.  It returns a type of MyResponse.  So how can I define MyResponse to return a Success or Failure XML Element?

```
public MyResponse SaveMessage(MyRequest request) 
{            
     return new MyResponse();            
}
```

I can return a success message just fine, like this.  It's unwrapped and has an XML element of Success.  But I need to also be able to return an XML element of Failure and I can't do that using the same MyResponse type.

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
public class MyResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
    public Success Success { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: There are several ways to format your response.  Are you familiar with MessageContracts?  My response back needs to be in the above format depending upon if it is a success or failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using untyped messages and returned the message as follows (similar for failure):

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<Success xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\"></Success>"));

XmlDictionaryReader xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream,new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

return Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "xxx/xxx/xxxResponse", xdr);
```